# Sending image Via Push notification not working in iOS

Tags: swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per documentation I added NotificationExtension. Here is the code

```
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"

            //contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }

        Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(self.bestAttemptContent!, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}
```

The firebase console shows the image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However in debug didReceive never calls nor the notification i receive has the image, even tho i have set notification as persistent in my iPhone settings.

What needs to be done to fix this issue? How can I see if NotificationService is attached to my App properly

[

```
AnyHashable("google.c.a.ts"): 1575541521, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Test for imge";
        title = Test;
    };
    "mutable-content" = 1;
    sound = default;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_l"): Data, AnyHashable("fcm_options"): {
    image = "https://thevowapp.com/iphoneapp/peri/media/portstar.png";
}, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.sound2"): default, AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0, AnyHashable("gcm.n.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1575541521949602, AnyHashable("google.c.a.c_id"): 5702933232519496714]
```

[image]

Added Notification to Extension too but I dont see any Background mode atm, tho they are not required as the code is not there yet. The debugger still wont roll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your notification payload should include the parameter `mutable-content` inside the `aps`.

> **THIS PARAMETER IS IMPORTANT.**
>
> If not present inside the `aps`, then your NotificationService won't get called and you won't get the image on the right side of the notification.

From documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification):

> mutable-content : Int
>
> The notification service app extension flag. If the value is 1, the system passes the notification to your notification service app extension before delivery. Use your extension to modify the notification’s content.

Secondly, you will need to download the image inside your notificationService and attach it to the notification.

You can use the example below as a starting point. It depends how you send the image link inside your payload. If you will post your actual payload, then I can edit my post.

```
import UserNotifications
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            let apsData = request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
            let alertData = apsData["alert"] as! [String : Any]
            let imageData = request.content.userInfo["fcm_options"] as! [String : Any]
            bestAttemptContent.title = (alertData["title"] as? String) ?? ""
            bestAttemptContent.body = (alertData["body"] as? String) ?? ""

            guard let urlImageString = imageData["image"] as? String else {
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                return
            }
            if let newsImageUrl = URL(string: urlImageString) {

                guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: newsImageUrl) else {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
                guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: "newsImage.jpg", data: imageData, options: nil) else {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [ attachment ]
            }
            Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(self.bestAttemptContent!, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: Extension for Notification Attachment
extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    static func saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: String, data: Data, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let folderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = folderURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileIdentifier)
            try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: fileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
            return attachment
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you're missing the part where you actually download the image and add as an attachment to the notification.

Comment: I have put a debugger at that place and code never gets into that service.

Comment: Firebase also gives u to add         Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(self.bestAttemptContent!, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
 that will auto handle fcm, sadly its not working either

Comment: I updated my code to use your aps. Also, are you running the extension in XCode? Otherwise you will never be able to debug it. Select the extension as the target and hit Build on a real device.

Comment: as soon as i run the extension, it opens the app and then auto closes it after reaching main screen, like a crash, no error nothing

Comment: But when you run your app target, does it crash?

Comment: ok the crash was fixed as soon as i changed the bundle id of extension,

Comment: Do you have ```Background fetch``` and ```Remote Notifications``` enabled in your app's capabilities?

Comment: I have also added the data sent by FCM it does contain all the necassary info the image etc, If app is in forground, it calls didReceiveRemoteNotif... and still debugger is not called inside extension, if app is in background i do get notification but still debugger is not called

Comment: You need to run your extension, then turn the screen off, send the notification, and see if it works. Did you try using the ```saveImageToDisk``` function I provided?

Comment: Important thing for you to know: if you don't import Foundation into your extension, then you won't be able to debug the extension like the main app target.

Comment: check the edits pls. If you have any demo on git that would be helpful

Comment: But do you get the notification at all? Is it coming to the phone, but it simply doesn't have the image? Or it is not coming at all?

Comment: I am using ur exact code now, Notifs are coming, the image is missing and the debug control is not going inside the service at all. I have also enabled BG modes, remote notif and fetch. I am also using Firebase console to send image along with data so there could be no issue in payload

Comment: Atlast it worked, there was a tutorial that added App Groups too, after adding those it started giving me error that app extension must have prefix as app original bundle id, i fixed the bundle id , added app groups and now its working fine

Comment: Okay, I am glad it worked. I didn't suspect you didn't add the extension correctly :)

Comment: How do I get this to work without adding App Groups to my target? I am receiving the notification but the image is not appearing.

Comment: @MatChristensen There is no App Groups used in this answer. You'll need to create a separate question if you have difficulties making it work and your case is different.

Comment: @Starsky I DO NOT have App Groups enabled for my app. Muhammad's comment above said he got this working after he added app groups. I am not using app groups, and my push notification sends successfully but the rich media image does not work.

Comment: @MatChristensen Ah, okay. It was a long time ago since I answered this one, and didn't read now through all the comments. If you still face difficulties, maybe you could create a new question and paste the actual notification payload and the code you use and let me know the question link and I will try to help.